# How to make a div fixed size and other div occupy all remaining space?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am very new to web development(.NET). Maybe this question asked earlier but I didn't find proper solution for my requirement. I have a master page with a banner and a right sidebar that could inherit by all child page. here is my master page design code:

```
   <div id="topContent">.......</div>
 <div>
 <div id="rightContent" style="position: relative; float: right !important;">......</div>
<div id="mainContent" style="position: static;">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>       
</div>
 </div>
```

But this code for design not work perfectly exactly what I want. Here is my require design:
image of master page design
[image]

How could I achieve this using bootstrap and css? any suggestion or link appreciable. Thanks

Comment: does `#rightContent` has a fixed width.?

Answer (score 1):

1.You can use bootstrap grid system classes as well as.
Here is the link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

2.Added a snippet where I have made the same without bootstrap. Note: I have assumed the height and width based on the attachment. However, you can specify your own height and width.

```css
#topContent {
width:100%;
  background:blue;
  padding:10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#rightContent {
position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    min-height: 104px;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#MainContent {
background: orange;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid black;
  min-height:204px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
  <div id="topContent">Master page banner</div>
 <div>
 <div id="rightContent">Mater page sidebar</div>
<div id="mainContent">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
      <p>Child page content</p>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>       
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Bootstrap implementation

You can use the grid layout provided by the bootstrap for this.This will give you a responsive design too.

```
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <header>Master page banner</header>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <article>child page content</article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <aside>Master page sidebar</aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

and as for the "...a banner and a right sidebar that could inherit by all child page" I hope you mean a single page application.To achieve this you could use JSON/XML files to populate your child page content block(which is the article tab in the example that I have given above) while your side page and banner elements remains the untouched.

https://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework

I hope this helps: )

2. CSS implementation(easy&simple)

```css
header {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>Master Page banner</header>
<div>
  Child Page content
  <aside>Master Page sidebar</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use the bottom of right content from the child page with col-sm-8 and col-sm-4. For better understand please visit: [link](https://ibb.co/mkRGg5) @Nivetha